# Configuring aluminium Mac Japanese keyboard on 15.04

Tags: keyboard-layout, 15.04, mac, japanese

I have an aluminium Mac keyboard with Japanese layout. Using System Settings -> Text Entry, I can configure it easily as a regular Mac keyboard. However a lot of the non-alphabetic keys are mapped incorrectly. I have tried the Japanese (Macintosh) keyboard but it only gives me Japanese text - at present, getting all the English mappings is what I need. Is there a mapping somewhere or some way I can at least change the key-mappings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To type the alphanumeric symbols as they appear on a Japanese keyboard:

1. Open Language Support
2. Check that Japanese is installed
3. Under Keyboard Input Method System, select fcitx
4. Log out and back in
5. Open Text Entry
6. Click the + button
7. Scroll down and select Mozc (Fcitx)
8. Click Add
9. An orange あ should appear in the system tray. (If it doesn't--it might
   be a JP or EN icon, for example--click the language icon and select
   Mozc.)
10. Switch to alphanumeric (i.e., romaji) input by toggling the
    全角 key or by clicking on the あ, selecting Input Method, then Direct
    Input.

If, on the other hand, you want to type all the alphanumeric symbols as they would appear on an English (e.g., US) keyboard by memory, you can just install that keyboard and type regardless of what symbols are printed on the keys of the Japanese keyboard.

Comment: Same problem. Following @tyknkd instructions and after installing Japanese in the language support, there is no fcitx in step 3. only iBus, XIM and none are listed in the Keyboard Input Method System.
I have a 2017 macbook with Japanese keyboard layout using Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Finally added fcitx 4 by installing fcitx-mozc, the orangeicon appeared but that does not work because no alphanumeric is listed there.

Comment: This question and answer are for earlier versions of Ubuntu. For 22.04, the following post will probably be more helpful: 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1459992/on-ubuntu-22-04-lts-how-to-set-a-keyboard-layout-that-matches-a-japanese-keyboar